# Data Binding a Generic Object to WPF TreeView?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I have an XML file I deserialized into an object, and now I want to display that object in a WPF TreeView.   I have been looking in to Data Bindings with the WPF TreeView but I have not been able to find what I am looking for.

Is there a way to have the WPF TreeView display an object and it's children without knowing in advance what the object structure looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your object looks something like:

```
    Entity A
        Entity B
            Entity C
            Entity C
        Entity B
    Entity D
```

Create a hierarchical data template for each non leaf entity and a data template for each leaf entity.

I've found it easy to accommodate any type of mixed hierarchy if you have in your objects an ObservableCollection (called something like Items) at each level that contains the children of any type below it.

With this setup, the templates would look something like:

```
        <!-- entity a-->
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:EntityA}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items, Mode=OneWay}">
            <StackPanel>
              <!-- your content >
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <!-- entity b -->
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:EntityB}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items, Mode=OneWay}">
            <StackPanel>
              <!-- your content >
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <!-- entity c -->
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:EntityC}">
            <StackPanel>
              <!-- your content >
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <!-- entity d -->
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:EntityD}">
            <StackPanel>
              <!-- your content >
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
```

And the tree view binding:

```
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Items, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

This answer assumes you know the types of objects you are dealing with, but want to handle any structure/hierarchy of those objects, and if you don't know if a particular object type is going to be a leaf one or not, you can always use hierarchical data templates.

Comment: A good suggestion, but I was hoping to find out a way to display the object without knowing the type of object in advance.

Comment: Do you know in advance what fixed properties (such as name, description) in your objects you want to display, or do you need to show different properties based on the type of object encountered?  If it's the former, you should be able to use hierarchical data templates.  If it's the latter, I don't know how you would do that in xaml, I would probably create the tree view items in code behind while walking through the object heirarchy (using reflections or some other means).

Comment: I would like to be able to display the object in TreeView without knowing any of the properties of the object.  I will look in to using reflection to do this.  Unless there is some other means.

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide hierarchical data templates for all possible types.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that you'll find a clean data binding solution that allows for object ignorance, but given that you initially deserialized from XML, you can probably serialize back to XML.  Given that that is the case, you can then display the XML serialization data in the treeview control:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308063

From the article:

In the Form1.vb file, replace the entire code after the "Windows Form Designer generated code" section with the following sample code:

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
      ' Initialize the controls and the form.
      Label1.Text = "File Path"
      Label1.SetBounds(8, 8, 50, 20)
      TextBox1.Text = Application.StartupPath() & "\Sample.xml"
      TextBox1.SetBounds(64, 8, 256, 20)
      Button1.Text = "Populate the TreeView with XML"
      Button1.SetBounds(8, 40, 200, 20)
      Me.Text = "TreeView control from XML"
      Me.Width = 336
      Me.Height = 368
      TreeView1.SetBounds(8, 72, 312, 264)
   End Sub

   Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
      Try
         ' SECTION 1. Create a DOM Document and load the XML data into it.
         Dim dom As New XmlDocument()
         dom.Load(TextBox1.Text)

         ' SECTION 2. Initialize the treeview control.
         TreeView1.Nodes.Clear()
         TreeView1.Nodes.Add(New TreeNode(dom.DocumentElement.Name))
         Dim tNode As New TreeNode()
         tNode = TreeView1.Nodes(0)

         ' SECTION 3. Populate the TreeView with the DOM nodes.
         AddNode(dom.DocumentElement, tNode)
         TreeView1.ExpandAll()

      Catch xmlEx As XmlException
         MessageBox.Show(xmlEx.Message)
      Catch ex As Exception
         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
      End Try

   End Sub

   Private Sub AddNode(ByRef inXmlNode As XmlNode, ByRef inTreeNode As TreeNode)
      Dim xNode As XmlNode
      Dim tNode As TreeNode
      Dim nodeList As XmlNodeList
      Dim i As Long

      ' Loop through the XML nodes until the leaf is reached.
      ' Add the nodes to the TreeView during the looping process.
      If inXmlNode.HasChildNodes() Then
         nodeList = inXmlNode.ChildNodes
         For i = 0 To nodeList.Count - 1
            xNode = inXmlNode.ChildNodes(i)
            inTreeNode.Nodes.Add(New TreeNode(xNode.Name))
            tNode = inTreeNode.Nodes(i)
            AddNode(xNode, tNode)
         Next
      Else
         ' Here you need to pull the data from the XmlNode based on the
         ' type of node, whether attribute values are required, and so forth.
         inTreeNode.Text = (inXmlNode.OuterXml).Trim
      End If
   End Sub
```

The article also details how to limit the data shown:

```
' SECTION 4. Create a new TreeView Node with only the child nodes.
         Dim nodelist As XmlNodeList = dom.SelectNodes("//child")
         Dim cDom As New XmlDocument()
         cDom.LoadXml("<children></children>")
         Dim node As XmlNode
         For Each node In nodelist
            Dim newElem As XmlNode = cDom.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, node.Name, node.LocalName)
            newElem.InnerText = node.InnerText
            cDom.DocumentElement.AppendChild(newElem)
         Next

         TreeView1.Nodes.Add(New TreeNode(cDom.DocumentElement.Name))
         tNode = TreeView1.Nodes(1)
         AddNode(cDom.DocumentElement, tNode)
```